# Can I send an e-mail with Scala/Lift without using system properties?

Tags: email, scala, lift

I'd like to implement a simple e-mail sending function as

```
object SendEmail {
  apply(smtpServer: String, login: String, password: String, from: String, subject: String, message: String) {
    //... implementation...
  }
}
```

All the examples I've found set system properties to initialize a mail transport, but I'd like to have that simple, flexible and concurrency-safe function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is sufficient for you, but you can create a session like that:

```
javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props)
```

props being a `java.util.Properties` (did you mean that by system properties?) instance.

Then you can create a message.